# Streaming an MP4 file

Tags: streaming, mp4

Is it possible to stream an MP4 file over HTTP? If so, would this prevent people from downloading it, or would it still be easy for people to download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its possible to stream mp4 over http. you need to set mime-type to "video/mp4".

its like any other http request-response, so people can download it using standard http commandline tools (wget, curl)